# Is spark overwrite save mode atomic?

Tags: apache-spark

Using spark overwrite mode to write dataset deletes old files in the partitions and write the new data. Is this process atomic ? If the job fails while overwriting the data, will spark revert the old files present in the partitions ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/transactional-writes-cloud-storage.html) post in databricks is not (emphasys mine):

> It is sometimes useful to atomically overwrite a set of existing
>   files. **Today, Spark implements overwrite by first deleting the
>   dataset, then executing the job producing the new data**. This
>   interrupts all current readers and **is not fault-tolerant**. With
>   transactional commit, it is possible to “logically delete” files
>   atomically by marking them as deleted at commit time

But they also offer an alternative to achieve atomic overwrite

Comment: "But they also offer an alternative to achieve atomic overwrite". Could you further explain this ? How can we achieve it ?

Comment: Use delta as it provides atomic operations ;)

Answer (score 2):

The overwrite operation is atomic as it firsts delete the old dataset and then produces the new data, however you can loose data in event the job or any of the task fails. Also if some other job is reading the dataset, will also fail as the file has been deleted. With transnational commit, it is possible to “logically delete” files atomically by marking them as deleted at commit time.

Atomic overwrite can be toggled by setting "spark.databricks.io.directoryCommit.enableLogicalDelete true|false"

Answer (score 1):

The question/answer is depending on the format u want to write.

Imagine two formats:

**"Delta"**:
If u are using delta format then the compution is atomic. This means internally it computes, writes the data and stages the commit in the delta meta table if successfull. Also after staging the data the old snappy compressed files are still lying in the folder. Based on the retention time that is in default 30 days I think the data is still there for rollback/repair purposes. Based on vacuum this retention time can vary.

**"Parquet"**:
For Parquet files, it deletes and writes. So no atomic operation is going on here and the data could get corrupted or loosed.

**"Use Case"**:
Imagine u are writing data and you recognize that u are overwriting a very large dataset with a single node. This takes a really long time.. For delta u can cancel it without destroying your data. For Parquet keep the process running when u not backuped the data before.